# How to avoid running a function when paths list is empty and just return the task

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem, my program is crashing whenever the filePaths doesn't returns any paths. This happens because the filePath doesn't exist or has been created/published yet. How can I handle my function when filePaths is empty? Because my function GetData() is running each minute, and if it doesn't have any FilePaths, I just want to make it return the task, with no results. And then it will try again.

I got an async Task Main() that calls on the GetData() function every minute.

```
  public async Task<Data[]> GetData()
    {
        var filePaths = GetPathsContainingData();
        var tasks = filePaths
            .Select(f => _ReadAndParseFromPaths(f))
            .ToArray();

        return await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: You should check for null or empty `filePaths` before using it.

Comment: Check that _filePaths_ is being valid, and if not return a Task<Data[]> object you should create by using [`Task.FromResult(resultData)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult) (_resultData_ of course being whatever Data[] value you want to have as a result when _filePaths_ is not valid)

Comment: Could you show me how it should be written? :) @ChrisOlsen

Comment: @elgonzo so, I want to return null, since we have no data, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> if it doesn't have any FilePaths, I just want to make it return the task, with no results.

The point of `async` and `await` is that you can write asynchronous code naturally. If you want to code up this logic, write it the same way you would if it was any other method: "if it doesn't have any FilePaths, then return no results":

```
public async Task<Data[]> GetData()
{
  var filePaths = GetPathsContainingData();
  if (!filePaths.Any())
    return new Data[0];

  var tasks = filePaths
      .Select(f => _ReadAndParseFromPaths(f))
      .ToArray();

  return await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable. How do I return no result? :)

Comment: It's literally right there in the code: `return new Data[0];` If you want to return `null` instead, then write `return null;` instead.